# Generic concurrent bounded buffer in C

Tags: c, concurrency, queue

I just implemented a generic concurrent queue in C, and I'd like some feedback on my implementation, as well as the logic in handling generic data and concurrency.

buffer.h

```
#ifndef BOUNDED_BUFFER_H
#define BOUNDED_BUFFER_H

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _boundedBuffer BoundedBuffer;

BoundedBuffer* allocBoundedBuffer(size_t capacity, size_t dataSize);
void destroyBoundedBuffer(BoundedBuffer* buf);

void dequeue(BoundedBuffer* buf, void* dest, size_t destSize);
int enqueue(BoundedBuffer* buf, void* data);

#endif
```

buffer.c

```
#include "boundedbuffer.h"
#include "scerrhand.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (a) <= (b) ? (a) : (b)

struct _node {
    /*
    A buffer node.
     */

    void* data;
    struct _node* nextPtr;
};

struct _boundedBuffer {
    /*
    A concurrent buffer with limited capacity.
    */

    size_t capacity;
    size_t numElements;
    size_t dataSize;
    struct _node* headPtr;
    struct _node* tailPtr;
    struct _bufferConcurrencyTools* tools;
};

struct _bufferConcurrencyTools {
    /*
    A set of tools to handle concurrency for a bounded buffer.
    `mutex` is a lock used to mutual exclusion access to the buffer,
    `empty` and `full` are condition variables used respectively for when
    the buffer is empty and for when it is full.
    */

    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t empty;
    pthread_cond_t full;
};

static struct _node* _allocNode(void* data, size_t dataSize) {
    /*
    Allocates a new node for the bounded buffer, initializing its value to
    the given one, and returns it.

    Returns NULL if the node could not be allocated.
    */

    struct _node* newNode;
    if (!(newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct _node)))) {
        // malloc failed; return NULL to caller
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!(newNode->data = malloc(dataSize))) {
        // malloc failed; return NULL to caller
        return NULL;
    }

    // copy data into new node
    memcpy(newNode->data, data, dataSize);

    newNode->nextPtr = NULL;

    return newNode;
}


static struct _bufferConcurrencyTools* _allocBufferConcurrencyTools() {
    struct _bufferConcurrencyTools* tools;
    /*
    Allocates a _bufferConcurrencyTools struct and initializes its mutex lock and cond vars;
    then returns a pointer to it.

    Returns NULL if memory for the struct could not be allocated.
    */

    if (!(tools = malloc(sizeof(struct _bufferConcurrencyTools)))) {
        return NULL;
    }
    pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t full;
    pthread_cond_t empty;

    // initialize condition variables
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_cond_init(&full, NULL));
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_cond_init(&empty, NULL));

    tools->mutex = mutex;
    tools->full = full;
    tools->empty = empty;

    return tools;
}

BoundedBuffer* allocBoundedBuffer(size_t capacity, size_t dataSize) {
    /*
    Initializes and returns a new empty buffer with the given capacity.
    */

    assert(capacity > 0);

    BoundedBuffer* buf = malloc(sizeof(BoundedBuffer));
    if (!buf) { // malloc failed; return NULL to caller
        return NULL;
    }
    buf->capacity = capacity;
    buf->dataSize = dataSize;
    buf->numElements = 0;
    buf->headPtr = NULL;
    buf->tailPtr = NULL;
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NULL(buf->tools = _allocBufferConcurrencyTools());

    return buf;
}


void dequeue(BoundedBuffer* buf, void* dest, size_t destSize) {
    /*
    Pops the node at the head of the buffer and returns its value.

    If the buffer is empty, waits until there is at least one element in it.
    */

    // NULL can be passed as dest if we just want to pop the element without saving it; however
    // if we want to save it somewhere, destSize must be greater than 0 bytes

    assert(buf);
    assert(!dest || destSize > 0);

    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_mutex_lock(&(buf->tools->mutex))); // gain mutual exclusion access

    while (buf->numElements == 0) { // buffer is empty: wait
        SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_cond_wait(&(buf->tools->empty), &(buf->tools->mutex)));
    }

    struct _node* node = buf->headPtr; // get buffer head node
    if (dest) {
        // copy node data to destination
        memcpy(dest, node->data, MIN(buf->dataSize, destSize));
    }
    buf->headPtr = node->nextPtr;
    buf->numElements--;

    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_cond_signal(&(buf->tools->full))); // wake up a producer thread (if any)
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZpthread_mutex_unlock(&(buf->tools->mutex))); // waive mutual exclusion access

    // done outside of critical section to avoid doing costly syscalls in mutual exclusion uselessly
    free(node->data);
    free(node);
}

void destroyBoundedBuffer(BoundedBuffer* buf) {
    /*
    Frees every remaining element in the buffer, then frees the buffer
    and sets the passed pointer to NULL
    */

    assert(buf);

    while (buf->numElements) {
        dequeue(buf, NULL, 0);
    }
    free(buf->tools);
    free(buf);
    buf = NULL;
}

int enqueue(BoundedBuffer* buf, void* data) {
    /*
    Allocates a new node with the given value and pushes it to the tail
    of the bounded buffer.

    If the buffer is full, waits until there is at least one free spot.

    Returns 0 on success, -1 if it is unable to allocate memory for the new node.
    */

    assert(buf);
    assert(data);

    // allocate new node outside of critical section to keep it as short as possible
    struct _node* newNode = _allocNode(data, buf->dataSize);

    if (!newNode) { // malloc failed; return -1 to caller
        return -1;
    }
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_mutex_lock(&(buf->tools->mutex))); // gain mutual exclusion access

    while (buf->numElements == buf->capacity) { // buffer is full: wait
        SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_cond_wait(&(buf->tools->full), &(buf->tools->mutex)));
    }

    if (buf->numElements) {
        buf->tailPtr->nextPtr = newNode;
    }
    else {
        buf->headPtr = newNode;
    }
    buf->tailPtr = newNode;
    buf->numElements++;

    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_cond_signal(&(buf->tools->empty))); // wake up a consumer thread (if any)
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_mutex_unlock(&(buf->tools->mutex))); // waive mutual exclusion access

    return 0;
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "module/boundedbuffer.h"
#include "module/scerrhand.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


void* produce(void* buf) {
    puts("producer started");
    while (1) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int n = (int)ceil(rand()) % 22;
        void* ptr = &n;
        SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NEG_ONE(enqueue((BoundedBuffer*)buf, ptr));
        printf("produced: %d\n", n);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void* consume(void* buf) {
    puts("consumer started");
    while (1) {
        int n;
        dequeue((BoundedBuffer*)buf, &n, sizeof(int));
        printf("read: %d\n", n);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

BoundedBuffer* ref;

void cleanup() {
    puts("cleaning up...");
    destroyBoundedBuffer(ref);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    BoundedBuffer* buf;
    pthread_t consumerTid, producerTid;

    // create buffer
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NULL(buf = allocBoundedBuffer(atoi(argv[1]), sizeof(int)));
    ref = buf;
    signal(SIGINT, cleanup);

    // initialize cond vars and concurrency tools struct

    // start threads
    puts("gonna start produer");
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_create(&producerTid, NULL, produce, buf));
    puts("gonna start consumer");
    SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(pthread_create(&consumerTid, NULL, consume, buf));

    pthread_join(producerTid, NULL);
    pthread_join(consumerTid, NULL);
}
```

scerrhand.h

```
#ifndef SC_ERR_HAND_H
#define SC_ERR_HAND_H

#include <stdlib.h>
// makes a system call and exits if return value is not zero
#define SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NZ(s) if(s) { puts("System call failed with nonzero status"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

// makes a system call and exits if return value is -1
#define SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NEG_ONE(s) if((s) == -1) { puts("System call failed with status -1"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

// makes a system call and exits if return value is NULL
#define SYSCALL_OR_DIE_NULL(s) if((s) == NULL) { puts("System call returned NULL"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't start names with an underscore

The C language reserves some [identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier) starting with one or two underscores. While your code may work, it is best to avoid it. It's also more common to write this:

```
typedef struct BoundedBuffer BoundedBuffer_t;
```

So the `struct`'s name has no prefix or postfix, the `typedef`'ed name has `_t` appended to it. However, the `_t` suffix is also problematic since it is reserved by POSIX. Note that you can also give both the same name if you like:

```
typedef struct BoundedBuffer BoundedBuffer;
```

## Naming things

You have some very generic function names in your code, like `enqueue()` and `dequeue()`. This might cause problems in larger projects. The typical solution to this problem in C is to prefix all the functions with the name of the module they belong to. So:

- `allocBoundedBuffer()` -> `BoundedBuffer_alloc()`
- `destroyBoundedBuffer()` -> `BoundedBuffer_destroy()`
- `dequeue()` -> `BoundedBuffer_dequeue()`
- `enqueue()` -> `BoundedBuffer_enqueue()`

## Merge `_bufferConcurrencyTools` into `_boundedBuffer`

I don't see why you are doing a separate allocation for `_bufferConcurrencyTools`, and storing a pointer to it in `_boundedBuffer`. I would just merge it completely into `_boundedBuffer`:

```
struct _boundedBuffer {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t numElements;
    size_t dataSize;

    struct _node* headPtr;
    struct _node* tailPtr;

    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t empty;
    pthread_cond_t full;
};
```

## Use `pthread_*_init()` to initialize the mutex and condition variables

The proper way to initialize non-`static` mutex and condition variables is to use [`pthread_mutex_init()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_init.3p.html) and [`pthread_cond_init()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_init.3p.html):

```
BoundedBuffer* allocBoundedBuffer(size_t capacity, size_t dataSize) {
    BoundedBuffer* buf = malloc(sizeof(BoundedBuffer));
    ...
    pthread_mutex_init(&buf->mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&buf->empty, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&buf->full, NULL);
    ...
}
```

## Consider using a circular buffer instead of a linked list

You are using a linked list to store buffer entries. However, that means you need to allocate and free `_node`s. In particular, it might increase memory fragmentation. Also, while each `_node` looks small (it's only two pointers), the memory allocator also has to store metadata about each allocation. An alternative to using linked lists is to use a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). If you allocate a buffer large enough to hold `capacity` elements, you only need to do one allocation when creating the buffer.

## Only one condition variable is needed

While it seems like two condition variables would be better, you will actually never have a situation where both the producer and the consumer are waiting at the same time (if they would, it would be a deadlock). So a single condition variable is enough, and just as efficient.

## Make `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` symmetric

There is an asymmetry between `enqueue()` and `dequeue()`: `enqueue()` just gets a pointer, but `dequeue()` gets a pointer and a size. I would expect that either no size is given to either function, and `buf->dataSize` is used in both cases, or you pass a size to both functions. But that also brings me to:

## Let the caller allocate memory for each entry

Your buffer implementation also takes care of allocating and freeing memory for each entry. It also needs to copy data into and out of the entry. I recommend that instead, your buffer implementation only worries about storing pointers, and doesn't allocate memory for the stored data. This places the burden on the caller to allocate memory if necessary. However, consider that sometimes, no memory allocation was necessary to begin with, for example:

```
void *produce_coinflips(void *arg) {
    static const char *strings[] = {"heads", "tails"};
    BoundedBuffer *buf = arg;
    srand(time(NULL);

    while (true) {
        enqueue(buf, strings[rand() % 2]);
    }
}
```

Copying the strings in this case would just be unnecessary overhead. The dequeueing operation should just `return` the pointer that was previously enqueued, so that the corresponding consumer for the above example can look like this:

```
void *consume_coinflips(void *arg) {
    BoundedBuffer *buf = arg;

    while (true) {
        puts(dequeue(buf));
    }
}
```

## Consider using Doxygen

I see you added comments to your code explaining what each function does, what parameters are expected and what they return. This is good practice, but it can be made even better by writing these comments in [Doxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) format. This allows the Doxygen tools to create a reference manual for your code, and it can even check the comments themselves, and can warn if you forgot to document a function, or forgot to document a parameter or return value.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that sticks out as highly suspect is this loop:

```
    while (1) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int n = (int)ceil(rand()) % 22;
        sleep(1);
```

You're re-seeding on every iteration, which means that any random state from the previous iteration is obliterated. Given the context - this is in a test method - you probably just want to `srand()` once, outside of the loop.